# Parse Excel spreadsheet to enter into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I wish to parse an Excel spreadsheet so the data can be checked and then entered into a MySQL database. If possible, I would like to do so purely in PHP but am open to other suggestions if thus is not recommended. Can any libraries etc. be recommended to get at the data in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to export your Excel data as CSV file,
as it is a simpler data exchange format.
Also PHP has very good inbuilt CSV parser to add your data to database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: You can even read the CSV directly from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

I also like python : http://www.python-excel.org/